# A couple of Sitecore questions

Tags: web-parts, sitecore, frontend

I have a couple of Sitecore questions.

1. The standard Canteen Webpart is supposed to show Today's Menu on front-page, if a canteen is choosen. Mine doesn't. It just links to my choosen canteen. How do i fix this?
2. In the News List webpart, you automatically show a list-picture/thumbnail, and if you don't it's still the same height. I just wanna remove the list-picture from the News List, and the height should just fit the text.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about Sitecore and not Sharepoint? Sitecore does not have web-parts, they have modular "renderings" which are broken down into three things: XSL renderings, sublayouts, web controls. Those translate to XSLT, ASCX User Controls, C# Web Controls, respectively

Comment: I'm talking about Sitecore Intranet Portal. There's Webparts in System>Modules>Webparts.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. SIP was the key the understanding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my version of SIP, doesn't have the Canteen module with Today's Menu in the webpart. And for the NewsList question, i just edited the .ascx file and removed the picture code. Works perfect.